# When code is contained inside < > for Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

When using vb.net, if code is contained inside "< >" signs, like a namespace, what is it telling the compiler to do? Also, what would these be signs be called when used like this?

To give clarity to the question; I know that parentheses "( )" are generally used for arguments and that brackets "[ ]" are used to declare a new type, but I cannot find what the less than/greater than signs do when used in a similar capacity.

I've looked through my reference books and attempted to research this through the internet but I haven't come up with an answer. Most likely because I don't know what exactly these would be named. I always results that talk about the relational operators, which is not what I'm looking for.

Here is an example of what I'm looking at:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel.Design

'<CLSCompliant(True)>
<System.ComponentModel.DefaultEvent("DataReceived")> _
Public Class SerialDF1forSLCMicroCon
Inherits MfgControl.AdvancedHMI.Drivers.DF1ForSLCMicroPLC5
Implements System.ComponentModel.IComponent
Implements System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize

Private Shared ReadOnly EventDisposed As New Object()
Public Event Disposed As EventHandler Implements System.ComponentModel.IComponent.Disposed

Protected m_synchronizationContext As System.Threading.SynchronizationContext
```

Specifically I am looking at the line that contains

```
<System.ComponentModel.DefaultEvent("DataReceived")> _
```

Comment: Show an example of such code.

Comment: One way that syntax is used is with generics. Please edit the question with an example of the code you've seen, that way we can know for sure.

Comment: That denotes an [attribute](https://www.bing.com/search?q=vb.net+attributes&form=EDGTCT&qs=PF&cvid=baeed4b650e94060a3d5c1d6620ec098&refig=1d94faa5b8d04cfddb528a03b7f46b47&cc=AU&setlang=en-GB&elv=AY3%21uAY7tbNNZGZ2yiGNjfN0RuGEkNg2KilmzZ0l3cbVva6u4YPJVoU9K605rhPbJk5CcZYHb4E%21E%21ujxx8LmP01RAjaccBb76OvrURumvey&plvar=0).

Comment: @SamM, chevrons (angled brackets) are only used in C# for generics.  VB uses parentheses for enclosing generic type arguments.

Comment: Brackets are not used to declare a new type.  Brackets are used to force a keyword to be interpreted as an identifier.  For instance, if you wanted to name a property `Class` you would have to enclose the property name in brackets or you would get a syntax error for incorrectly using the `Class` keyword: `Public Property [Class]() As SomeType`.

Comment: What is contained inside those chevrons is actually a type, not a namespace.  Just like in the rest of your code, that type may be qualified with the namepace it's a member of.  The type must inherit the `Attribute` class.  A special syntax is used where the word "Attribute" can be omitted from the type name and you provide constructor arguments without the `New` keyword, plus you can provide property values as named arguments.

Answer (score 1):

That is an [attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/).  It is a way of attaching metadata (additional information) to your code that can be queried later using reflection.

For example, let's say you have a series of classes (e.g. Customer, Contact, Order, Product, etc.), each of which corresponds to a database table, and inherits from a `DbTable` base class that has a common `DeleteAll()` method.

Now, it might be that your database table names don't match your class names.  In that case you can define an attribute that adds additional information to your class, providing the table name, as shown here:

```
<DbTableName("CUST01")>
Public Class Customer
   Inherits DbTable

   ...
End Class
```

This indicates that your "Customer" objects are stored in the "CUST01" table in the database.

You might implement the attribute like this:

```
Public Class DbTableNameAttribute
   Inherits System.Attribute

   Public Property Name As String

   Public Sub New(value As String)
      Name = value
   End Sub
End Class
```

Lastly, in your base `DbTable` class, you would implement `DeleteAll()` like this:

```
Public MustInherit Class DbTable
   Public Sub DeleteAll()
      ' Use reflection to retrieve the attribute.
      Dim attributes = Me.GetType().GetCustomAttributes()
      Dim dbTableNameAttribute = attributes.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.GetType() = GetType(DbTableNameAttribute)

      If dbTableNameAttribute IsNot Nothing Then
         Dim tableName As String = CType(dbTableNameAttribute, DbTableNameAttribute).Name

         ' tableName will contain the value specified in the attribute (e.g. "CUST01")
         Dim sql As String = "delete from " & tableName

         ' ... at this point you would send the delete command to your database ...
      End If
   End Sub
End Class
```

Now, in the specific example you cite:  `<System.ComponentModel.DefaultEvent("DataReceived")>`

What is likely happening is that the `SerialDF1forSLCMicroCon` class probably has multiple events, and the attribute is providing a hint to the designer that the "DataReceived" event is the default one.  You'll see a similar sort of thing with a Windows Forms Button.  If you click the events for a Button, there are many, but the "Click" event is always highlighted by default, as it is the most commonly used one.